# Gradle build is hanging without failure, DefaultFileLockManager acquiring and releasing lock on daemon addresses registry

Tags: java, gradle, build, artifactory, gradlew

I have several gradle-based projects and on all of them recently I've become unable to execute a ./gradlew clean build. Upon running this, the  When I run with the --debug flag, I get stuck on `> Building 7% > :compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':compileClasspath'` and it never moves forward.

When I ran with the `--debug` flag, I got this output regarding the `DefaultFileLockManager` acquiring and releasing a daemon lock, but this has been unhelpful. Here is the last bit of the Gradle debug log that I see.

```
11:22:57.079 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
11:22:57.080 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 203][route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
11:22:57.080 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443
11:22:57.080 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to maven.vaadin.com/54.86.23.48:443
11:22:57.080 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to maven.vaadin.com/54.86.23.48:443 with timeout 0
11:22:57.098 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
11:22:57.098 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
11:22:57.098 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Starting handshake
11:22:57.141 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Secure session established
11:22:57.141 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer principal: CN=*.vaadin.com, O=Vaadin Ltd, L=Turku, ST=Western Finland, C=FI
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer alternative names: [*.vaadin.com, vaadin.com]
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  issuer principal: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established 10.10.2.46:54773<->54.86.23.48:443
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request HEAD /vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom HTTP/1.1
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:22:57.142 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:22:57.163 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-203: Close connection
11:22:57.166 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
11:22:57.166 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-203: Close connection
11:22:57.166 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 203][route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
11:22:57.166 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom]
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.jar
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource metadata: https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.jar
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP HEAD: https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.jar
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 204][route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to maven.vaadin.com/54.86.23.48:443
11:22:57.167 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to maven.vaadin.com/54.86.23.48:443 with timeout 0
11:22:57.186 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
11:22:57.186 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
11:22:57.186 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Starting handshake
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Secure session established
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer principal: CN=*.vaadin.com, O=Vaadin Ltd, L=Turku, ST=Western Finland, C=FI
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer alternative names: [*.vaadin.com, vaadin.com]
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  issuer principal: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established 10.10.2.46:54774<->54.86.23.48:443
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request HEAD /vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.jar HTTP/1.1
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:22:57.207 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:22:57.230 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-204: Close connection
11:22:57.234 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
11:22:57.234 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-204: Close connection
11:22:57.234 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 204][route: {s}->https://maven.vaadin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
11:22:57.234 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.jar]
11:22:57.234 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'info.magnolia:magnolia-module-content-dependencies:1.6.1' in repository 'vaadin-addons'.
11:22:57.234 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetaDataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: info.magnolia:magnolia-module-content-dependencies:1.6.1 [changing = false]
11:22:57.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/enterprise/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom
11:22:57.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/enterprise/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom
11:22:57.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource metadata: https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/enterprise/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom
11:22:57.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP HEAD: https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/enterprise/info/magnolia/magnolia-module-content-dependencies/1.6.1/magnolia-module-content-dependencies-1.6.1.pom
11:22:57.236 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
11:22:57.236 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
11:22:57.236 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
11:23:06.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:06.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:06.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:16.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:16.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:16.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:26.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:26.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:36.181 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:36.181 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:46.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:46.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:46.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:46.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:46.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:46.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:46.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:56.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:23:56.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:56.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:56.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:56.181 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:23:56.181 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:23:56.181 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:06.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:06.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:06.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:06.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:16.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:16.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:16.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:16.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:16.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:26.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:26.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:36.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:36.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:36.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:36.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:36.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:36.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:36.176 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:46.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:46.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:46.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:46.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:46.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:46.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:46.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:56.172 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:24:56.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:56.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:56.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:56.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:24:56.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:24:56.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:25:06.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:25:06.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

Comment: To others having this problem: The `DefaultFileLockManager` related messages are not indicative of whatever the problem is. They are part of a normal repeated health check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for gradle work properly, you need to configure at least 3 kind of proxies on Linux/macOS which are

- gradle proxies - inside gradle.properties
- maven proxies - inside ~/.m2/settings.xml
- bash proxies - inside ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Apart from these proxy settings, you also need to double check your proxy settings of your OS, e.g. on mac, check "System Preferences" -> "Network" -> "Advanced..." -> "Proxies". You may need try to turn on/off this system proxies.

However, sometimes, like your case, it may not because of connectivity problems, but due to permission issues. If you ever ran your gradle commands using "sudo" then some of the directories generated during executing the gradle commands may become owned by "root". Hence, when you try to run gralde commands using normal user, these directories are not accessible. The bad thing is that gradle does not give you any information or even hints to "permission".

The solution to this is as below.

- To find all the files and directories that are owned by root or belong to root group:

  $ls -alR | grep -w root > list.txt

The result of this command will be output to file list.txt, open it to check all the files and directories. For example you may see the output something as below:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 86 root  admin   2.9K Jun 29 20:30 Applications/
drwxr-xr-x+ 65 root  wheel   2.2K May 19 00:19 ***/.gradle
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root  wheel    68B Nov 20  2016 ***/build
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136B Jun 29 20:31 .gradle
drwxr-xr-x    3 employee  staff   102B Nov 10  2015 Samsung/
drwxr-xr-x    7 employee  staff   238B Jul  6  2016 VirtualBox VMs/
drwxr-xr-x    3 employee  staff   102B Nov  4  2016 android-ndk/
drwxr-xr-x    3 employee  staff   102B Aug 31  2016 bin/
```

- To find the exact location of those files or directories

  $find "$PWD" | grep your-file-name
- Delete those files or directories.

  $ sudo rm -rf your-file-name

Usually, you need change your directory to below locations to perform above actions to delete all the files with root user.

- ~/.gradle – The .gradle cache under your user’s “Home” directory
- /.gradle – The .gradle cache under your project root
  directory
- [project-root]/[module]/build – The .gradle cache under
  your gradle module directory.
- ~/.m2 – The Maven cache directory under
  your user’s “Home” directory

Then start over a gradle sync, the problem should be resolved.

---

You can find more detailed descriptions from below blogs:

1. [gradle-sync-issue-on-debian-os-due-to-user-does-not-have-permission](https://arophix.com/2018/07/01/gradle-sync-issue-on-debian-os-due-to-user-does-not-have-permission/)
2. [android-gradle-plugin-3-0-sync-issue](https://arophix.com/2018/07/01/android-gradle-plugin-3-0-sync-issue/)
3. [gradle-proxy-configuration](https://arophix.com/2018/04/17/gradle-proxy-configuration/)

Comment: A more precise command to "find all the files and directories that are owned by root or belong to root group" would be:
`find -user root -o -group root`

Comment: Any idea how to fix it on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case setting proxy in **~/gradle/gradle.properties** helped:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=hostname
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly caused this issue in my case, but the problem was a version of the Gradle wrapper that was too low. The version causing this issue was `4.0`, it was fixed by using `4.9`.

You can change the version of the wrapper by first setting it in your `build.gradle` file:

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion '4.9'
}
```

To install the correct wrapper jar in your project, go to your project root directory and run

```
gradle wrapper
```

This will download the appropriate jar file into your `gradle/wrapper` folder and update the `gradle-wrapper.properties`. Then you can run `./gradlew build` as usual.