# Spring Boot - Run project error: Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a question, I am a total beginner

I downloaded a project (gradle project) from:
https://start.spring.io/

I enter the console and enter the command (in project folder)

**./gradlew bootRun -d**

and I get something like this:

```
2020-12-31T14:20:25.381+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock 
acquired on daemon addresses registry.

2020-12-31T14:20:25.381+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] 
Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

2020-12-31T14:20:25.382+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] 
Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.

2020-12-31T14:20:25.382+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock 
acquired on daemon addresses registry.

2020-12-31T14:20:25.382+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] 
Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [4m 22s]
> :bootRun
```

How to slove it ?

Comment: It seems like thread deadlock or some heavy operation during gradle task execution, please share full logs in debug mode, and you can try to do dump via jps and jstack.
see issue solving in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/daemon-stuck-waiting-to-acquire-shared-lock-on-daemon-addresses-registry/19063/8

Comment: Please share more details as longs and versions that you are using.

Comment: Try using the gradle version 4.9. See if the below link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976794/gradle-build-is-hanging-without-failure-defaultfilelockmanager-acquiring-and-re