# GitLabRunner CI very slow on Windows 10

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci-runner, windows-server

I have `GitLabRunner 14.4.0 (4b9e985a)` installed as a service on `Windows Server` with follow parameters:

[image]

Sorry for non English, but I guess it is clear what is going there.

Nothing is run on the server except GitLab-Runner, so all resources are free.

Here is the `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 5
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "TorgovayaSystema"
  url = "https://srvgitlab.maxi-net.ru/"
  token = "xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "cmd"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

I tried both shells - `cmd` and `pwsh`.

I run task from follow `CI` config:

```
stages:
  - build

build-modules-job:
  stage: build
  variables: 
    ErrorActionPreference: stop
  script:
    - .\gradlew.bat compile
  tags:
    - cpp
```

When I run `gradlew.bat compile` separately on this machine, it takes one minute, but inside the runner in goes for timeout, it was one hour before.

**So, my problem is 1 hour timeout**

I tried to use `-d` flag, and get many:

```
2021-11-12T18:21:33.777+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:33.777+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:33.777+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:33.778+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:33.778+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:33.778+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.777+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.777+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.778+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.779+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.779+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-11-12T18:21:43.780+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

I guess it is not a problem in gradle or CI configuration, thus git initialization take much time too...
I guess it is something in `gitlab-runner.exe`...
Have someone ideas?

Comment: What you're seeing is related to the gradle daemon. Have you tried running gradle without the daemon and does that resolve your issue? If so, you're likely running into a permissions issue; GitLab's runner uses a non-privileged user on your system, which is likely a different user than you're using to test. That may be causing issues.

Comment: Is there anything about your system configuration that may account for this, like a network proxy configuration? Also as Patrick states, check your user permissions on the user for the gitlab-runner. This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128852/5747944

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I tried with my own acount using --user and --password option, and --no-daemon also, so it solved part of the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so first of all, I want to thank people who wrote comments under my post.

I actually tried both suggested ways:

1. Run `gitlab-runner.exe` with my own acount using `gitlab-runner install --user user --password password` option
2. Run `gradle task --no-daemon`

Also, very important, when you use `gradle` or `maven` inside batch scripts, you need to execute it with `call` statement, for exapmle:

3. Using call: `call gradle compile --no-daemon`

In such a way, the script will be continue.

But the system was still hanging up...

I tried to run all this in separate batch with compilation commands, which are made the same, the `gradle` plugin made for build the `Borland CPP`:

4. Using script with manual run of `bpr2mak.exe` and `make.exe`

Than I found the problem... When I run it from inside `Gradle` plugin, it used such a piece of code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envVars.toArray(new String[0]), cwd);
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = out.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.log(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}

process.waitFor();
return process.exitValue();
```

So there is some specificity of `Runtime.exec()` and there is blocking read in `out.readLine()` with mutual block of `process.waitFor()`. You can read here [about](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).

So here the process hunged up! It freezed over:

```
Loaded cached pre-compiled headers
DocAssImpl.cpp:
FmDocAss.cpp:
```

When I **ADDED** stderr **BEFORE** stdout, it continues, and gives me an expected message.

Whole code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envVars.toArray(new String[0]), cwd);
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

String line;
while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.log(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}

while ((line = out.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.log(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}

process.waitFor();
return process.exitValue();
```

Resulting messages;

```
BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

So after all, the problems were in include paths... Our build system widely uses `subst`, so for successfull complilation, it was necessary to add follow commands to the build scripts:

```
subst L: C:\Work\projects\Library\
subst P: C:\Work\projects\TradingSystem\
```